# Shortening PHP code when comparing multiple MYSQL columns

Tags: php, mysql

I use lengths of code similar to this repeatedly in my scripting because I cannot find a shorter way to to compare the MYSQL columns

```
if ($them['srel1']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Adventist'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel2']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Agnostic'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel3']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Atheist'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel4']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Baptist'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel5']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Buddhist'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel6']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Caodaism'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel7']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Catholic'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel8']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Christian'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel9']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Hindu'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel10']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Iskcon'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel11']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Jainism'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel12']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Jewish'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel13']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Methodist'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel14']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Mormon'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel15']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Moslem'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel16']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Orthodox'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel17']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Pentecostal'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel18']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Protestant'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel19']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Quaker'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel20']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Scientology'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel21']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Shinto'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel22']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Sikhism'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel23']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Spiritual'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel24']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Taoism'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel25']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Wiccan'){$seek11pts=5;}
if ($them['srel26']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Other'){$seek11pts=5;}
```

EG: `if ($them['srel1']=="Y" AND $me['Religion']=='Adventist'){$seek11pts=5;}`
I check to seek if the MYSQL column `srel1` has a value of Y. if it does then I check to see if the column `Religion` equals Adventist. If both are true then $seek11pts=5, if they are not both true then nothing happens.
There are 26 srel type columns with either a Y value or null.  There are also 26 different values for Religion as you may see. This is but one section of my code. I have multiple HUGE code groupings like this and I'd love to be able to reduce it down to a few lines. I was thinking some kind of array for the religions and another for the numerical endings of the srel columns but I cant get it.

Comment: Ohh eeeem geeee

Comment: For a start you could create an array `[0 => 'Adventist', 1 => 'Agnostic', ...]` And then iterate through the array. `for($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) { if ($them['srel'.($i+1)]=="Y" AND $me['Religion']==$myArray[$i]){$seek11pts=5;} }`

Comment: there is no mysql code here, no idea where the variables come from, or what your trying to achieve.

Comment: This smells like something you could achieve using the database almost entirely if you designed your data right. You may be trying to solve the problem at too low a level. Perhaps you could take step back and describe your data and what you're actually trying to achieve with all these comparisons? Certainly pulling data from a database into big arrays and trying to match it in PHP is often solved by using the database to do the matching: that's what they're for.

Comment: This feels like something that should be solved further upstream with a db redesign.

Comment: There is probably no reason to have 26 `srel` columns.

Comment: @AbraCadaver as far as I know there is since all the srel columns are based on a binary system of Y or null. User A selects one religion while User B selects any religion thru multiple choice. 26 choices, each with their own value to compare to the one value of User A's choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this current code you can use this:

```
<?php

$religions = array(1 => 'Adventist','Agnostic','Atheist','Baptist','Buddhist','Caodaism','Catholic','Christian','Hindu','Iskcon','Jainism','Jewish','Methodist','Mormon','Moslem','Orthodox','Pentecostal','Protestant','Quaker','Scientology','Shinto','Sikhism','Spiritual','Taoism','Wiccan','Other');

$count = count($religions) + 1;

for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ($them["srel$i"]=="Y" && $me['Religion']==$religions[$i]) {
        $seek11pts=5;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While there *are* ways to accomplish what you ask, you should instead *seriously* consider restructuring your data.

#### Better data structure

If your data had a structure more similar to the following:

```
db.person
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Nick |
| 2  | Bob  |
| 3  | Tony |
+----+------+
PrimaryKey: id

db.religion
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | Atheist |
| 2  | Jainism |
| 3  | FSM     |
+----+---------+
PrimaryKey: id

db.person_religion
+--------+----------+
| person | religion |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | 2        |
| 2      | 2        |
| 2      | 3        |
| 3      | 1        |
| 3      | 2        |
| 3      | 3        |
+--------+----------+
UniqueIndex: (person,religion)
```

...everything you're trying to do could be done with simple queries.

```
SELECT me.id, me.name, meR.name as religion, count(them.id) as matches
FROM person me
LEFT INNER JOIN person_religion meRlookup
    ON me.id = meRlookup.person
LEFT INNER JOIN religion meR
    ON meRlookup.religion = meR.id
LEFT INNER JOIN person_religion themRlookup
    ON meRlookup.religion = themRlookup.religion
LEFT INNER JOIN person them
    ON themRlookup.person = them.id
GROUP BY meR.id
```

Comment: I'm sure that would work except I have 178 columns per user. Its a very detailed signup form

Comment: The main point here remains. If 26 of those columns are "religion", religion-user relationships should be stored as described here. I suspect that most of your other "columns" involve similar data-structures.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using laravel or lumen, since these include a "queries generator" that just write a little code (NOTHING SQL) to make queries and that ..